# Apostrophe CMS relationship values are not being saved

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have set up some relationship values for my Apostrophe CMS deployment and the values are not saving. I see the fields show up and I am able to populate them, but when I save the item, the values disappear. I am not getting any error messages and nothing seems to be failing. 
Here is the contents of my beforeConstruct in the index.js of the components:

```
    options.addFields = [
      {
        name: '_linkPage',
        label: 'Case Study',
        type: 'joinByOne',
        withType: 'apostrophe-page',
        idField: 'pageId',
        required: true,
        help: 'Please pick a Case Study',
        filters: {
          projection: {
            title: 1,
            slug: 1,
            type: 1,
            tags: 1,
            pageHeader: 1,
            pageThumbnails: 1
          }
        },
        relationshipsField: '_cardData',
        relationship: [
          {
            name: 'cardTitle',
            label: 'Card Title (override)',
            type: 'string',
            inline: true
          },
          {
            name: 'cardText',
            label: 'Card Text (override)',
            type: 'string',
            inline: true
          }
        ]
      }
    ].concat(options.addFields || []);
  }
```

Here are my versions of apostrophe and apostrophe-related projects:

```
"apostrophe": "2.99.0",
    "apostrophe-groups": "^0.5.34",
    "apostrophe-link-widgets": "^1.0.5",
    "apostrophe-monitor": "^2.0.5",
    "apostrophe-workflow": "2.25.0"
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. I'd much rather manage data in this way.

Comment: Have you checked if updating to the latest version of Apostrophe and apos-workflow resolves this?

Comment: Updating to the latest version of Apostrophe breaks my deployment. I haven't dug into it too much, but It makes it so that none of my fields are editable. That is why I'm pinned at 2.99.0

Comment: @alexbea I was able to get updated, but no change here are my new versions
```
    "apostrophe": "^2.106.2",
    "apostrophe-employee-profile": "git+https://github.com/blaineo/apostrophe-employee-profile.git",
    "apostrophe-groups": "^0.5.34",
    "apostrophe-headless": "git+https://github.com/blaineo/apostrophe-headless-page-by-slug.git",
    "apostrophe-link-widgets": "^1.0.5",
    "apostrophe-monitor": "^2.0.5",
    "apostrophe-people": "^0.5.63",
    "apostrophe-workflow": "^2.34.0"
```

Comment: I finally ran a test and I think I have your answer below. Apologies for the detour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `relationship` schema field property is only available on [`joinByArray` schema fields](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/reference/field-types/joinbyarray.html#relationship-properties-and-joinbyarray).

In a `joinByOne` relationship, you theoretically can set any related properties (like your `cardText`) directly on the piece doing the joining since there's only one relationship. In a `joinByArray` field, where you are joining to multiple different documents, each of those relationships might deserve their own properties to help describe the relationship, so the extra fields are available.